# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS display issue on boot

Tags: boot, display-settings, ubuntu-20.04

I'm trying to boot Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS and its booting to a black screen with a cursor. Nothing happens after that so I cannot get to a login screen. I thought that it may be a graphic drivers issue so I've tried the following...

edited the grub menu for booting with nomodeset option

Tried booting with Advanced options and got to the root prompt

uncomment WaylandEnable=false in /etc/gdm8/custom.conf

lshw -c display
*-display UNCLAIMED product: GT218M [GeForce G 105M] vendor: NVIDIA Corporation configuration: latency=0 I cant see any display drivers which should have been nvidia

ubuntu-drivers devices
I can see the following drivers driver: bcmwl-kernel-source - distro on-free driver: nvidia-340 - distro non-free recommended driver: xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin

because I have been facing issues since yesterday, I had already updated these drivers once.

I've also tried to boot in recovery mode for both 5.8.0.36-generic and also in 5.8.0.34-generic with option: dpkg (Repair broken packages) but it doesn't seem to work.

Any directions will be very helpful.

Comment: Try an updated Video driver and try updating the Kernel. 5.8.9 is current or reasonably so.

Comment: i also faced this problem, please see here : [https://askubuntu.com/questions/1305862/after-an-update-and-reboot-in-ubuntu-20-04-i-can-no-longer-complete-the-boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1305862/after-an-update-and-reboot-in-ubuntu-20-04-i-can-no-longer-complete-the-boot)

Comment: i also faced a problem like this : please see this post [https://askubuntu.com/questions/1305862/after-an-update-and-reboot-in-ubuntu-20-04-i-can-no-longer-complete-the-boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1305862/after-an-update-and-reboot-in-ubuntu-20-04-i-can-no-longer-complete-the-boot)